# Only FadeOut a Jquery Item IF the user is not clicking within it and using it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pop-up box triggered via jquery that appears in the upper right to give the user information about what they have done on the site.  Currently, there is am X they can click to close it, but it also fades away after a while via this script:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#ratingtext-'+imgId+ItemType+Type2+'').fadeOut() }, 2500);
```

The box is up and to the right and meant to be inconspicuous which is why we use the fadeout.

However, I am adding in a Comments box, so after they rate an item, they can leave a comment as well.

Is there a way I can craft the above script so that if they are clicking on or in that DIV or using it, that the DIV won't fadeout, but if they leave it alone, it will still fade out?

Comment: Please could you provide more of your code?

Comment: Please show the html for the pop-up box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$(".comment_being_focused").is(":focus")) {
        $('#ratingtext-' + imgId + ItemType + Type2 + '').fadeOut();
    }
}, 2500);
```

http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Answer (score 1):

If you save the return value from `setTimeout` you can call `clearTimeout` with it to cancel the fade out.

Something like this:

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(...);
$('#ratingtext-'+imgId+ItemType+Type2+'').one('mouseover', function() { clearTimeout(timeoutID); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `clearTimeout()` function. `setTimeout` returns an id, so you can cancel the timeout by calling the clearTimeout function on that id. So, you could say `var id = setTimeout(function() { //some code });` and calling `clearTimeout(id)` to cancel the timeout before it happened.

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

JS:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var myVar;

        function start() {
            myVar = setTimeout(function() {
                $('#ratingtext-' + imgId + ItemType + Type2 + '').fadeOut();
            }, 2500);
        }

        function stop() {
            clearTimeout(myVar);
        }

        start();

        $("button").click(function() {
            stop();
            start();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps :)